# Applying Application.ScreenUpdating to all worksheet apart from first row

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know how to apply the following to my worksheet apart from the first 2 rows?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 23

Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
Target.Font.ColorIndex = 2

Cells.Font.Bold = False
Target.Font.Bold = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If Target.Row > 2 Then`

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Exactly! many thanks, just couldn't get it ... was using 'If ROW > 2'... completely forget about the target!

Comment: Please mark it as the answer to help future visitors!